# Remove the space in the end of text

Tags: autohotkey

I'm just starting to learn to use Autohotkey, mostly for text expansion, ie when I type goo and it will become www.google.com. Problem is, in Windows, it always leaves a space in the end and that's annoying. What can I do to avoid that?

I tried added {bs} and {left 1} to the script but it moves the cursor before the last character eg www.google.com

Answer (score 3):

The reason there is a space at the end is because you're pressing <kbd>space</kbd> to end your hotstring. If you use the `O` option, it will omit the ending character. Try this:

```
:O:goo::www.google.com
```

More information can be found here in the official help docs: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself! My original code syntax was like this...

```
::goo ::www.google.com
```

Doing so leaves a space in the end

I changed it to...

```
::goo ::
Send, www.google.com
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `:*:goo::www.google.com`

The asterisk means that the hotstring will be activated without waiting for you to end the hotstring (though in this case, typing 'good' would pose a problem)